# Comparing dates if one date is NULL

Tags: sql-server

Why do I get different result from these two samples?

```
DECLARE @validFrom DATE
DECLARE @validTo DATE

SET @validFrom = GETDATE()
SET @validTo = NULL

IF (@validFrom = @validTo)
   PRINT 'same'
ELSE
   PRINT 'not same'
```

Result: not same

But this code does not work:

```
DECLARE @validFrom DATE
DECLARE @validTo DATE

SET @validFrom = GETDATE()
SET @validTo = NULL

IF (@validFrom <> @validTo)
    PRINT 'not same'
ELSE
    PRINT 'same'
```

Result: same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **CANNOT** compare a `NULL` with the regular equality / inequality operators - this will always return `NULL` as result, which is being interpreted as "not defined" or "false". This is **standard** SQL behavior*.

Therefore the check

```
IF (@validFrom <> @validTo)
```

will **always** be false.

You can **only** check for `NULL` with the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators - but **NOT** with `=` or `<>` or `<` or `<=` or any of those standard operators.

More detail in the official documentation : [Handling null values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/handle-null-values?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: But why does the first sample seem to work when I use =  ?

Comment: @KjartanValurÞórðarson: it doesn't - like the second, it will **ALWAYS** jump to the "false" part and print "not same" - in the first case, this just *happens* to be the right answer

Comment: My understanding was that the logical comparison yields null? Such that `NOT(@validFrom <> @validTo)` is also null rather than True?  (By saying the comparison yields False, you're implying that applying NOT can make it become a True. That's wrong, isn't it?)

Comment: @MatBailie: correct - the result of the comparison is `NULL` (undefined) - and doing a `NOT` before that will still result in a `NULL` - which will **also** be interpreted as "false"

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @validFrom DATE
DECLARE @validTo DATE

SET @validFrom = GETDATE()
SET @validTo = NULL

IF (@validFrom IS NULL AND @validTo IS NULL)
    OR (@validFrom = @validTo)
    PRINT 'same'
ELSE
    PRINT 'not same'
```

[Izik Ben-Gan NULL complexities – Part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/12/t-sql-queries/null-complexities-part-1)

Comment: I whant the result to be "same" if both values are null

Comment: @KjartanValurÞórðarson, fixed